# How do I prevent Chrome from constantly restarting after chrome://restart command?

Tags: google-chrome, reboot

I attempted to restart Chrome with the chrome://restart command. Now it cycles endlessly -- shutting down the browser, restarting, trying to open up the old session, executing the restart command again, ad infinitum. How can I disable this? Or clear out the old session?

Comment: Delete the session from <chrome data folder>/Default. Older versions have `currentsession` and `lastsession` (or something analogous), and newer versions have a `Sessions` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to prevent the old session from starting by:

1. Starting chrome programmatically in incognito mode (chrome.exe --incognito)
2. Going to chrome://flags and disabling the "Better session restore" option.
3. Creating a new window (Ctrl+N)
4. Navigating to one specific page, like stackoverflow.com
5. Close all Chrome browsers.
6. Open again.

Maybe there is an easier way to accomplish this, but this is what worked for me.

Comment: Looks like this was resolved in a subsequent build of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall Chrome ***as well as it's user data***.

And then install it again.